# How to get custom URL Button to display on Lightning record page?

Tags: custom-button, lightning-experience, page-layout

I know lightning doesn't support javascript buttons. I know there are alternative routes to do this with actions, lightning components, and visualforce. I'm asking how to do something that according to my research is supported but doesn't seem to work.

From the [spring '16 release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_url_button_support_lex.htm)

> Custom buttons and links that define their content source as URL are
>   now supported in Lightning Experience and the Salesforce1 mobile app.
>   This feature was previously available in Salesforce Classic only.

Seems straight forward. Create the button, add it to the classic page layout, see it in lightning. But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to get this thing to show up.

Here's the custom button, pretty basic
[image]

I've got it setup as the only button on the page layout, it's the assigned layout when I edit the page in lightning.
[image]

But in lightning I'm getting nothing
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Seems like I'm following the instructions outlined in this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_customization/units/lex_customization_buttons_links#Tdxn4tBK-heading6). Even though it's in the release notes, it's not mentioned in the [help docs on actions in lightning](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=5). Other peopler have had [issues](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pMELQA2) and have gotten it working eventually. What am I missing? Are there other factors to consider? Are those documented anywhere?

Comment: This was frustrating and terribly documented on Trailhead's part. The answer below worked for me. Minor note for beginners like myself: Salesforce1 = "mobile"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the Google Info custom button from the *Salesforce1 & Lightning Actions bucket*  to the **Salesforce1 & Lightning Actions section** in the layout for it to appear in the Lightning Experience view of the page.

[image]

If you just move it to the **Custom Buttons** section (bottom part of the above screenshot), it shows in Salesforce classic view only.

In your screenshot, you added the button to the Detail page, so it shows in Classic only.  Add the button to the Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience Actions section just above it.

[image]

Comment: Yessss!! That's super easy, new it was something straight forward if hardly intuitive. You should answer this as well https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/196955/how-to-get-custom-visualforce-button-to-display-on-lightning-record-page.

Comment: which one? the link gets back to this same question.

Comment: bad copy and paste, edited the comment