# Contact detail page does not show standard and custom buttons according to the page layout in lightning mode

Tags: lightning, custom-button

I want to create a detail custom button named 
'Maps' in contact object. I created custom button the proper way.
I added the button in proper page layout along with some other standard and custom buttons.
On checking the details page, I did not see any custom buttons. The layout was not followed. I saved and refreshed but to no avail. 
The layout is followed in classic mode but not in lightning mode. Other display types except Detail Page Button work. They open the URL but behavior is not followed. It always opens URL in a new window. Please help.
 [image: Here is how I created the button]

[image: page layout]

[image: contact detail page buttons]

Comment: please check the answer in a similar question here : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/196951/how-to-get-custom-url-button-to-display-on-lightning-record-page

Comment: Thankyou for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addition of button in the 'detail' section adds the button only in classic mode. To add the button in lightning mode or mobile application, add it in the 'salesforce mobile and lightning action' section. See the below image.

[image: Proper way to add detail button in lightning mode]